# Alias fields for JSON parse

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

Users on my homepage can upload json fields which I need to parse. I am looking for specific fields which may have a lot of alias names. I am not sure what I should do to check for these alias names.

What I am doing right now is nothing else than checking all possible properties via if/else, but I assume there are much better options for my situation:

```
function tryParseHeaders(data) {
    var header = null

    var normalizedHeader = {}

    if(data.Header)
        header = data.Header
    else if(data.header)
        header = data.header
    else if(data.Headers)
        header = data.Headers
    else if (data.headers)
        header = data.header

    if(header.ProjectIdVersion)
        normalizedHeader.projectVersion = header.ProjectIdVersion
    else if(header.ProjectVersion)
        normalizedHeader.projectVersion = header.ProjectVersion
    else if(header.Version)
        normalizedHeader.projectVersion = header.Version

    return normalizedHeader
}
```

Comment: If you asked me, you need to put your foot down. Set up an api and have _them_ program to it. You shouldn't have to try to coerce their data to a format you expect, it should be the other way around. If they use an older standard you prepared, you could maybe make tools to help with that conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `hasOwnProperty` function and then access the object as a dictionary:

```
function tryParseHeaders(data) {
    var index = 0;
    var normalizedHeader = {}
        var headerAliases = ["Header", "header", "Headers"];
    var versionIdAliases = ["ProjectIdVersion", "ProjectVersion", "Version"];

    for(index = 0; index < headerAliases.length; index++) {
        if(data.hasOwnProperty(headerAliases[index])) {
        normalizedHeader.header = data[headerAliases[index]];   
      }
    }

    for(index = 0; index < versionIdAliases.length; index++) {
        if(data.hasOwnProperty(versionIdAliases[index])) {
        normalizedHeader.projectVersion = data[versionIdAliases[index]];    
      }
    }

    return normalizedHeader;
}
```